# Use SCIM API to send data from Azure AD to another endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I am trying to recreate a model to use SCIM to send data from an Azure AD to an endpoint.

Could someone please help me to understand the process and how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Have you checked the tutorial? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I am still trying to understand it.. I want it to be a alternative to the Graph API, where I could just use GET in the AD to query data.

Comment: As per the answer, there is no general SCIM into Azure AD. There is specific support for some vendors e.g. Workday. There is a Microsoft SCIM library if you want to roll your own - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-microsofts-scim-sample-a6e7dddbca71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - you want to make REST calls against Azure using the SCIM standard to retrieve data?

Unfortunately, Microsoft/Azure does not have a SCIM service, only a SCIM client - meaning that Azure AD can be used to make requests to external SCIM service providers (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE..) but has not implemented SCIM for accessing/managing Azure AD resources.